Inverse birthday estimation 2
problem:
we're not necessarily on Earth
we've chosen all individuals born on the same planet
we've chosen N individuals to find 2 individuals having the same birthday.
Question:
how many (K) days there are in a year on this planet?
(yes this is in a way related to famous birthday probability problem
in the birthday problem K=365 and you have to choose N=23 people to find 2 people sharing the same birthday with the probability P=50%
in this problem you've chosen N people to find exactly 2 people sharing the same birthday. given this information we're trying to provide a best guess at the number of days per year (K))
the motivation behind this question is I'm trying to estimate an odd/rare probability (e.g. the probability of winning in a certain lottery) how would you do that? you can just use plain old monte carlo method (e.g generate lottery tickets randomly until one of them wins (e.g. until one of them is 1,2,3,4,...) and then conclude saying that the probability you're looking for is 1/W (where W is the number of tickets generated)). Or you can use this inverse birthday trick. (e.g. generate tickets until 2 of them collide, plug in the number of tickets generated (=N) into the formula yet to be discovered, (probability=1/K) surely going to be way faster than the monte carlo method (albeit at the expense of more memory required))
I hope that makes sense
EDIT:
trying to rephrase again:
check the code here: https://github.com/imre84/inverse_birthday
let's assume that:

QRandomGenerator (lott_single) is a true unbiased random number generator
unsigned int is able to store arbitrarily big integer numbers
lott_single provides an even distribution for arbitrarily big lott_single::max values

question: what's the limit function of f (generated on the standard output of this application) when magic_parameter approaches positive infinity?

This question is similar to: Birthday probability of $k$ people and $n$ days a year such that at least $2$ people have the same bday. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Angelica, to use the terminology of that question: I've chosen k people to find exactly 2 with the same birthday. how much is n?

@Angelica This question, as written, says nothing about probability, so it's not the same as the one you cited. The first $N-1$ individuals all had different birthdays, so there are at least $N-1$ days in the year.  That's all we know for sure.

"I hope that makes sense"  Not to me it doesn't.  Birthday implies, but you never state that this is similar to the famous birthday probability problem but you never say so.  Are you supposed to find within a probability.  If so then the words "had to" and "exact" are inappropriate. I'd say either: We only have to choose $2$ people to get two with the same birthday.  We just deliberately pick two that have the same birthday. Or if  we have the worst luck possible the we can't ever assume we have a pair until we exhausted all dates.  So the year has $N-1$ days.

no sense here, if the population is $m$, then the probability of having at least two same birthdays among a sample of $N\leq m$ is $1-\prod_{i=1}^N\frac{m-i+1}{m}$.
